# How to add Global Search for one column using Kendo Grid in Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

Im using Kendo grid and trying to add Global search only for first 'product name' column.

Here you will find the code : https://github.com/SanDeshpande/Angular-KendoGrid-GlobalSearch

I have tried filter option but it gives the search bar inside the grid,which is not required.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the input event of the INPUT element and either process the Grid data accordingly or create a FilterDescriptor and filter the Grid via the built-in helpers like [filterBy()](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/filterBy/) or [process()](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/api/process/):

[1) Filter the data via Array.filter()](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vzjhy?file=app/app.component.ts)

[2) Filter the data via filterBy()](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vzjhy-u7wohc?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hello, Its working thanks..  Could you pls tell me how this is done when the data is Griddataresult observable. im referrring following example and i have implemented the same steps in my project as well :  [dataBinding Example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/)

Comment: As it already has the dataStateChange event handled, you can just create a filter descriptor in the Input's input event handler and call the dataStateChange event handler, passing it the modified state (the existing state with the new filter added), e.g.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4gdrr?file=app/app.component.ts